# What do we know about a subgroup that is conjugate to exactly one other subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose I have a group $W$.

Let $\Lambda(W)$ be the subgroup lattice of $W$. We can take that lattice and draw an edge between any two subgroups $A$ and $B$ where $wAw^{-1} = B$.

Any subgroup corresponding to an isolated vertex is normal.

I'm curious what we know about a subgroup $A$ that's conjugate to exactly one other subgroup $B$.

I can show that the group elements $g$ that fix $A$ setwise by conjugation form a group.

If I have two group elements $g$ and $h$ such that $gAg^{-1} = hAh^{-1} = A$

Then $hgA(h \cdot g)^{-1} = hgAg^{-1}h^{-1} = hAh^{-1} = A$.

The inverse is also a group element.

$$ g^{-1}Ag = \{ g^{-1} \cdot a \cdot g : a \in A \} = \{ g^{-1} \cdot a^{-1} \cdot g : a \in A \} = \{ g \cdot a \cdot g^{-1} : a \in A \} = gAg^{-1} = A $$

I think from here we can conclude that $W$ acts on $F = \{A, B\}$ by elementwise conjugation and each group element either fixes $F$ elementwise or swaps $A$ and $B$.

All this gives us, though is a homomorphism $\varphi : W \to 2$ where $2$ is the $2$-element group.

Can we learn anything more concrete about $W$, $A$, or $B$ themselves?

Comment: Equivalently, the normalizer $N_W(A)$ has index $2$ in $W$. There are many examples. Seems too general to be able to say anything more interesting

Comment: So the normalizer $N_W(A)$ is itself normal in $W$, and $A$ is $2$-step subnormal in $W$. The smallest example is a non-normal subgroup of order $2$ in the dishedral group of order $8$.